# Is it possible for an iOS device to broadcast as an iBeacon and monitor for iBeacons at the same time?

Tags: ios, ibeacon

Is it possible for an iOS device to broadcast as an iBeacon and monitor for iBeacons at the same time? I'm currently doing this with a custom raspberry pi solution and want to know if it could translate to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this if the app is in the foreground (transmission always requires the app to be in the foreground.)  You can see a demo of this by using my [Locate app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/locate-beacon/id738709014?mt=8) in the AppStore.

An important thing to realize is that the device will not pick up its own transmission in a scan.

Comment: Thanks for always providing clear and helpful iBeacon answers David!